# "error: invalid operands to binary expression" coming from inside of string library component

Tags: c++, string, clang

I'm trying to build a `vector` of `strings` that all use the same custom allocator to allocate memory. I have the following code:

```
typedef alloc_adaptor<char, BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator> mono_adaptor_char;
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, mono_adaptor_char> mono_string;
typedef alloc_adaptor<mono_string, BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator> mono_adaptor_string;
typedef std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<mono_adaptor_string> mono_allocator;

BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator alloc(pool, sizeof(pool));
std::vector<mono_string, mono_allocator> container(&alloc);
container.emplace_back("qwer"); // ERROR ON THIS LINE
std::cout << container[0] << std::endl;
```

(As a side note, I'll happily take any suggestions to reduce the insane verbosity of this).

Everything in the BloombergLP namespace is from the [opensource BDE libraries](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde). `alloc_adapter` is a wrapper for Bloomberg style memory allocators to make them work with standard containers:

```
template <typename T, typename ALLOC>
struct alloc_adaptor {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const& const_reference;
    ALLOC* alloc;
    alloc_adaptor() : alloc(nullptr) {}
    alloc_adaptor(ALLOC* allo) : alloc(allo) {}
    template <typename T2>
    alloc_adaptor(alloc_adaptor<T2, ALLOC> other) : alloc(other.alloc) {}
    T* allocate(size_t sz) {
        return (T*)alloc->allocate(sz * sizeof(T));
    }
    void deallocate(void* p, size_t) {
        alloc->deallocate(p); }
};
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:2139:34: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const allocator_type' (aka
      'const alloc_adaptor<char, BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator>') and 'allocator_type' (aka
      'alloc_adaptor<char, BloombergLP::bdlma::BufferedSequentialAllocator>'))
    if (__str.__is_long() && __a != __str.__alloc()) // copy, not move
```

To my naive it looks as if somewhere in the hand-off of the allocator from the vector to the string, something is/isn't being declared as `const`. I'm quite confused by this. Any suggestions for what I may be missing?

Comment: Your code example references multiple non-standard classes that obviously come some vendor-supplied external library. An authoritative answer is not possible without having complete information about those custom classes, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information. My best guess is that std::operator<< overload cannot handle the vendor-specific customized subclass of std::basic_string that you're using here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the `vector`, `string`, and `scoped_allocator_adaptor` are all standard. I've provided code and links for the non-standard pieces now, so I think complete information is now available. Also, why are you referencing `std::operator<<`? The error occurs on the line before the `<<`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: the libraries in question are actually publicly available from [github](http://github.com/bloomberg/bde/).

Comment: There was nothing in your question that specifically stated at which point the error has occured,  beyond just some vague claim to a compilation error that occurs somewhere. The sum total of the issue was "When I compile the code, I get the following error", without anything more specific as to where the error actually occurs (sadly, I'm not a mind reader). As such, the most likely location for the error appeared to be the << operator. If you don't want others to guess what your error is, you have to do a better job of providing relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, your custom allocator adaptor (`alloc_adaptor<...>`) is lacking equality/inequality operators entirely. They may be absent from your quote but it seems adding should solve the problem:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
bool operator== (alloc_adaptor<T, A> const& a0, alloc_adaptor<T, A> const& a1) {
    return a0.alloc == a1.alloc;
}
template <typename T, typename A>
bool operator!= (alloc_adaptor<T, A> const& a0, alloc_adaptor<T, A> const& a1) {
    return !(a0 == a1);
}
```